# WPF - TabItem Contents still visible when tabitem.visibility=hidden

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is there any good solution to this problem.

I have set the

> tabitem.visibility=hidden

but the contents in this tabitem is still visible. I want to hide all the contents of tabitems.

I did search for a resolution but no luck. In 2009 someone raised this issue but still NOW there is no result on how to achieve this. URL: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/e4d23ace-0eb5-45a9-86f5-43c6351cb0ed/

Thanks

Comment: It could be helpful if you post the xaml-code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fix your problem use Visibility.Collapsed. Visibility.Hidden won't change the layout and so you would always have that empty space in the tab header. Be sure to change the selected tab as well when that happens.

I wouldn't recommend hiding tab items like that though. Conceptually they are either open or closed.

Comment: had same issue this morning. have been searching for about an hour to figure this out as it take 2 sec in winforms it with setting visibility = false. Collapsed DOES NOT remove the content. still shows for me. i had to set `<TabControl SelectedIndex="2">` to point o my third tab. otherwise the first tab still shows.

Comment: The visibility problem is only for the first TabItem. Put it in another position and then Collapse will work correctly. Funny, but true.

Comment: Andrea Antonangeli: No, I have the problem on not-the-first. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to hide the TabControl by setting it's visibility to Visibility.Hidden or switch to another tab (maybe an empty one?). You didn't give much reason why you do it, but if you really want to hide all controls in the tabcontrol, you can also iterate through tabItem.Children and set their Visibility to Visibility.Hidden.

Comment: This could work but this does not make logic sense because I have to keep TabControl for each TabItems. If we have to create 10 Tabs then we have to create 10 TabControls...

Comment: And why can you not make an additional (empty) tabitem and switch to that? Edited my answer.

Comment: Um... +ve can do that. Just thinking if there is any other way because I have around 10 screen and need to fix all of them.

Comment: Well there's no `SetVisibilityOfAllChildren(Visibility v)` method in TabItem if you wanted to know that ;-)