# Content of TabItem stays visibile when set to Collapsed/Hidden

Tags: wpf, xaml, visibility, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have a TabControl that displays default information for objects that can be selected by the user in a list.
Unfortunately not all of the TabItems apply to all types of objects. That's why I decided to use DataTriggers to hide some of them in such cases. When testing however I noticed that when the a TabItem is already selected while being set to collapsed then only the header vanishes, but the content of the TabItems stays visible.

When searching for a solution I only found this very old thread here:
[WPF - TabItem Contents still visible when tabitem.visibility=hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949890/wpf-tabitem-contents-still-visible-when-tabitem-visibility-hidden)
I was wondering if there was is nicer solution today. The only thing that I could think of would be a custom TabControl that would look somehow like this:

```
public class MyTabControl : System.Windows.Controls.TabControl
{
    public MyTabControl() : base()
    {
        var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Items);
        view.CollectionChanged += TabControl_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void TabControl_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (TabItem tabItem in e.NewItems)
            {
                tabItem.IsVisibleChanged += TabItem_IsVisibleChanged;
            }
        }
        else if (this.Items != null)
        {
            foreach (TabItem tabItem in this.Items)
            {
                tabItem.IsVisibleChanged += TabItem_IsVisibleChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private void TabItem_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TabItem tabItem = sender as TabItem;
        if (tabItem != null && tabItem.IsSelected && tabItem.Visibility != Visibility.Visible)
        {
            this.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

However this means that I have to use my own TabControl over the default one. Can anyone think of an even nicer solution?